# Authorization in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication

I need add authorization in a Flutter app (REST API).

In the body, we have the `type` of authentication (e.g., login or telegram) as well as the credentials (`login` with `password`). If the authentication is correct, we receive a token, which is saved.

How do I make this work in Flutter.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to implement `OAuth` and login with password options?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1GIa.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvYbW.png

Answer (score 0):

You can make requests with the flutter [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http).
For communicating with your API, I would write an ApiClient class that adds the token to each request header. You can do that by adding a `Map<String, String>` with header information (see https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseRequest-class.html) like this

```
http.post('https://your-api-endpoint.com', headers: {'X-Api-Token': yourToken});
```

Now to get there you need to store your token somewhere and retrieve it. You can use the package [flutter_secure_package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) for that.